# Accessing resource file from JS file in c#.net

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I need to access the resource file keys from a js file, Is this possible or not?

For example if I want to set a popup message based on some conditions applied in .js file and want to get the text from a resource file according to the language then how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The are a few common approaches on howto deal with localization in your client side scripts. One would be creating a standalone localized javascript file for every language and culture. But this would not fit your requirement of using .net resource files. I find [this](http://madskristensen.net/post/Localize-text-in-JavaScript-files-in-ASPNET.aspx) solution very elegant and does precisely want you want.

Comment: Thanks Martijn for your replay. I had checked the solution there its a good approach, but for my case it seems to be a bit complex.